# Constructing TypeTags of higher-kinded types

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, scala-reflect

Given a simple parametrized type like `class LK[A]`, I can write

```
// or simpler def tagLK[A: TypeTag] = typeTag[LK[A]]
def tagLK[A](implicit tA: TypeTag[A]) = typeTag[LK[A]]

tagLK[Int] == typeTag[LK[Int]] // true
```

Now I'd like to write an analogue for `class HK[F[_], A]`:

```
def tagHK[F[_], A](implicit ???) = typeTag[HK[F, A]] 
// or some other implementation?

tagHK[Option, Int] == typeTag[HK[Option, Int]]
```

Is this possible? I've tried

```
def tagHK[F[_], A](implicit tF: TypeTag[F[_]], tA: TypeTag[A]) = typeTag[HK[F, A]]

def tagHK[F[_], A](implicit tF: TypeTag[F], tA: TypeTag[A]) = typeTag[HK[F, A]]
```

but neither works for the obvious reasons (in the first case `F[_]` is the existential type instead of the higher-kinded one, in the second `TypeTag[F]` doesn't compile).

I suspect the answer is "it's impossible", but would be very happy if it isn't.

EDIT: we currently use `WeakTypeTag`s as follows (slightly simplified):

```
trait Element[A] {
  val tag: WeakTypeTag[A]
  // other irrelevant methods
}

// e.g.
def seqElement[A: Element]: Element[Seq[A]] = new Element[Seq[A]] {
  val tag = {
    implicit val tA = implicitly[Element[A]].tag
    weakTypeTag[Seq[A]]
  }
}

trait Container[F[_]] {
  def lift[A: Element]: Element[F[A]]

  // note that the bound is always satisfied, but we pass the 
  // tag explicitly when this is used
  def tag[A: WeakTypeTag]: WeakTypeTag[F[A]]
}

val seqContainer: Container[Seq] = new Container[Seq] {
  def lift[A: Element] = seqElement[A]
}
```

All of this works fine if we replace `WeakTypeTag` with `TypeTag`. Unfortunately, this doesn't:

```
class Free[F[_]: Container, A: Element]

def freeElement[F[_]: Container, A: Element] {
  val tag = {
    implicit val tA = implicitly[Element[A]].tag
    // we need to get something like TypeTag[F] here
    // which could be obtained from the implicit Container[F]
    typeTag[Free[F, A]]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17791973/1223622

Answer (score 4):

Does this serve your purposes?

```
def tagHK[F[_], A](implicit tt: TypeTag[HK[F, A]]) = tt
```

As opposed to using the implicit parameter to get the `TypeTag` for `F` and `A` separately and then composing them, you can directly request the tag you want from the compiler.  This passes your test case as desired:

```
tagHK[Option, Int] == typeTag[HK[Option, Int]] //true
```

Alternatively, if you have an instance of `TypeTag[A]` you could try:

```
object HK {
    def apply[F[_]] = new HKTypeProvider[F]
    class HKTypeProvider[F[_]] {
        def get[A](tt: TypeTag[A])(implicit hktt: TypeTag[HK[F, A]]) = hktt
    }
}
```

Allowing you to do:

```
val myTT = typeTag[Int]
HK[Option].get(myTT) == typeTag[HK[Option, Int]] //true
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't (`TypeTag[A]` is actually obtained from a data structure at the runtime, not inserted directly by the compiler).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov So you have an instance of `TypeTag[A]`?  Can you tell us more about what your set up looks like?  I've added a solution here for when you have an instance of `TypeTag[A]` and know `F[_]` at compile time.

Comment: I've added description of our situation to the question.