# Reifying higher-kinded type in a scala 2 macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.12

I have the following trait / macro definition:

```
trait Test[A[_]] {
  def hello: String
}

object Test {
  def getTest[A[_]]: Test[A] = macro Impl.getTest[A]
}

class Impl(c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._

  def getTest[A[_]](implicit tt: WeakTypeTag[A[_]]): c.Expr[Test[A]] = {
    reify {
      new Test[A] {
        override def hello: String = "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which i try to use like so

```
      val test = Test.getTest[List]
      println(test.hello)
```

However, when I try to build, i get the error "Macro expansion contains free type variable A defined by getTest in Test.scala.... Have you forgotten to use c.WeakTypeTag annotation for this type parameter? ".  What is the correct way for me to provide a typetag for a higher-kinded type?

Comment: I think there's an issue in your getTest method signature. You can try to change it to `def getTest[A[_]: WeakTypeTag]: c.Expr[Test[A]]` and see if error persist.

Comment: So there's some hoops to jump through to get context bounds to work for type constructors, but at the end the result is the same - A does not get bound in reification

Comment: Seems to work with quasiquote instead of `reify` in 2.13. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758334/how-to-test-type-conformance-of-higher-kinded-types-in-scala